# Can we add two delegates file in xcode?

Tags: delegates, xcode4, uitabbar

I want to add two delegates to my iphone app. Was just thinking if i could do this or not.
I have one tab bar control where in one tab i am showing one web view now in second tab i want to show my own coding which i have separately implemented. And I want to bring that code to this code. Can i do this by adding a new delegate in Xcode or i have to embed it in first delegate itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're talking about a second application delegate, in which case the answer is no. You should not have more than one app delegate per application. What you should do instead is take your own code and integrate it into the existing tab bar controller by adding another tab which loads your view controllers, etc.

Comment: so for integrating my code into another tab in tabbar do i need to add delegate file? I mean how should i integrate two delegate files? or is it ok to have second delegate when you have two seperate tabs in a tabbar control.

Comment: You *should not have* two delegate files. Take only your view controllers from the part you're integrating, and create from scratch a new tab that loads those controllers and content. If you need functionality from your second app delegate, manually merge the code with the other delegate. *Do not* try to use both application delegates in the same project.

Comment: thanks Tim. I will give it a try and will tell you if there are any other problems.